# Netbeans Code assistance on code templates

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a long list of Code Templates in NetBeans and I want to sort them somehow because I don't remember all of them. The abbreviation for my code templates is: user_template, something like this:

```
 alpha_sop  wich does:
 System.out.println(${cursor});
```

Also another one:

```
 alpha_psvm
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 ${cursor}
 }
```

And many many more... Is there a way that after I write alpha_ and press ctrl+space a list of all available templates that contain alpha_ dropdown in a list? Id kinda like to select from my own list...

Something like:

```
alpha_ ctrl+space
*Dropdown*
alpha_psvm (with description of code)
alpha_sop (with description of code)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sollution for the templates to expand on code assistant (sorry but names are in spanish :P hope you get the idea)

It is impostant to chose  CONTEXT where to apply those templates when pressing ctrl+space ...
[image]

And after adding a context you can properly expand:

[image: Small tutorial]

It is important that the templates are structured properly with abbreviation and description...

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using NetBeans 7.4 and it seems that <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd>

Does in fact give me a list of suggestions for Code Templates.

I am not sure if **CUSTOM** templates get registered in the Code Assistance and seems there's been some [bug reports](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=160771) already made.

[image: Code Assistance for Code Templates]

[Code Assistance in the NetBeans IDE Java Editor: A Reference Guide](https://netbeans.org/kb/74/java/editor-codereference.html)

Comment: What I expected was the same behaviour as for the built-in templates. For me it also does not make much sens to have a 
hugh stack of custom code templates and have to remember each and every abbreviation to be able to expand it with TAB 
or whatever. ... Reported in 2009 lol, is there still any sollution to managing a lot of templates?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality (autocompletion with code templates) does not exist in Netbeans.  However, you can customize the IDE to achieve this functionality.  See [autocompleteNB](https://github.com/rmarquez123/autocompletionNb) on GitHub.